# Можете ли вы поделиться api (JSON), которое позволит получать случайную цитату/шутку на русском языке?

Tags: json, api

Это api нужно для учебного проекта на js. То, что я нашла, работает нестабильно. Помогите пожалуйста, может кто-то, что-то использовал хорошее. Именно **на русском**.

Comment: а что вам мешает просто создать массив шуток и случайно выбирать из него шутку?

Comment: Не JSON, но тем не менее... https://bash.im/webmaster